# Checking if any AV devices are connected

Tags: objective-c, avkit

I have this code which assumes that an AV decide is connected...

```
AVCaptureDeviceInput *device_input = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice :
                                              [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType : AVMediaTypeVideo][0] error : nil];
```

How can I modify that code so that I get a message like this...

```
if (No AV devices were detected)
NSLog(@"No AV devices were detected");
else
NSLog(@"The following devices were detected...");
```

Thanks,
Len.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to check for audio device you can use below code-

```
-(void)checkForDevice{
    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

     if (error)
     {
        NSLog(@"%@", error); //problem with the device
     }
     else
     {
         //device is available  
     }
}
```

In the similar way you can check for vedio and other AV Devices.

Comment: Thanks, (I am new to XCODE, and Stackoverflow), I used your suggestion but I am getting this   [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice : videoDevice error : &error];  //Use of undeclared identifier 'error'

Comment: Thanks.  This will check for a built in device.  How could I modify that to check for other devices attached to the Mac.  I am using Video2PC digitiser attache to a digital camera and via a USB port?

Comment: OK, I have abandoned that digitiser and am now using a firewire connection that works. Thanks.